# Merge [Covariant] into [Covariance]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

I think [covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covariant) should be merged into [covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covariance) and be a tag synonym for it.

Fact is that [covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covariant) doesn't have a wiki description and only 33 questions are tagged with it whereas [covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covariance) has a wiki and 835 questions tagged and covers the same subject.

Additionally there already exist other tags for [contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contravariance) but not for [contravariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contravariant).

Comment: [tag:variance] is for statistics, not type theory.

Comment: It's relevant though, because "covariance" is also a thing in statistics.

Answer (score 11):

Right now two concepts are intermingled, the typing concept of covariance and statistical covariance.

Really it should be turned around the other way... primary tag of `covariant` (because this word isn't used in statistics) or `type-covariance`, move the statistical uses to `statistical-covariance`, and blacklist `covariance` due to the ambiguity.

Comment: You're throwing out the baby with the bath water - the term covariance is used in both worlds and according to the wiki the term is clearly attributed to the programming version. Stackoverflow is programming related so I'd rather see it as mentioned in the tag wiki: `Tag usage

    Do not use covariance for the measurement of the strength and direction of the linear relationship between two random variables (statistical context). Instead, use other related tags, for example, statistics.`

Comment: @Marwie: But the "programming version" is... both.  We aren't talking about a word like "type" or "class", which has a specialized meaning which is nearly ubiquitous in programming.  Rather, the type theoretic meaning of "covariance" is of interest only to a fraction of users, and the statistical meaning commands a similar level of interest, with a similar level of applied expertise.  When there's a near tie like that, disambiguated tags are the usual approach.  So [tag:statistical-covariance] and [tag:type-covariance] would be great.

Comment: Does it cause a similar level of interest in the programming context? When quickly checking through the first 50 frequent questions I see only the type-covariance related questions. Although I agree that there are cases when the tag was used in statistical relation even if it was not meant to. Does this already qualify to blow-up the tag name just to disambiguify a handful of statistics related questions?

Comment: @Marwie: Your results are biased by the people who did read the tag wiki.    Furthermore, when I click [tag:covariance] (my options default to seeing "newest" questions), the ratio is about 2:1 between the type-theoretic meaning which matches the tag wiki, and the statistical meaning which does not.  So yes, the level of interest is similar.  (The "frequent" list has probably already been retagged, so doesn't tell us anything)

Comment: It might even be better to use [tag:covariant-types] and [tag:covariance-statistic], because prefixes.

Comment: @Marwie: When I look at the first page of "newest covariance questions," about half of them are about covariance matrices.  If anything, it makes sense to move type covariance questions out of the covariance tag.

Comment: newest questions is biased as well, it reflects only the askers point of view. The topvoted covariance questions (not the tagged, but returned fulltext search) are maybe the best view and they strongly tend to the type-covariance. After reading a little bit more into the subject of ambigous tags and how SO deals with it, I changed my opinion and agree that a renaming makes sense. I tend to keep the `covariance` wording on both sides as it is the correct term for the subject. `Covariant` as such is maybe not used in statistic but it exists in physics as well so we wouldn't gain much.

Comment: I have no preference about pre or postfixing it with type/statistical - does it even make a difference for the users?